# merge в sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Дооброго времени суток! Делаю merge в алхимии, но поведение при этом не могу понять и в документации что-то не нашел ответов... Предположим есть модель с полем `many-to-one` (детали опущены):

```
class Parent(Base):
    bg_image = relation('Blob')
```

Когда я делаю merge для объекта Parent то все норм, `bg_image` (он же `Blob`) сливается с существующим в базе если он есть и в случае слияния статус `Blob` - `transient`.
Но вот когда у Parent появляется поле `childrens`:

```
class Parent(Base):
bg_image = relation('Blob')
childrens = relation('Children', cascade='merge')

class Children(Base):
   bg_image = relation('Blob', cascade='merge')
```

Статус у объектов `Children` такой как я и ожидаю `transient` но вот статус `bg_image` у `Children` всегда `pending` даже если в базе он есть, вот почему так? разве не должен merge работать рекурсивно? Спасибо!

Дополнение:

```
# создание основной записи
def create(self, data_parent):
    parent = _schema.load(data_parent)

    session.merge(parent)
    session.flush()

    return contest
```

В моем случае parent создается на основе внешних данных, при этом в данных указаны и `childrens` также и для них тоже указан `Blob`, у всех объектов Blob указаны первичные ключи, и получатся так что Bob связанные непосредственно с `Parent`  в коде выше это `Parent.bg_image` сливаются, а  Blob связанные с `Children` в коде это `Children.bg_image` создаются через `insert`

Comment: В документации описано как это работает с оговоркой как должна быть определена ассоциация `cascade="merge"` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge

Comment: @MikhailLazko так и есть и у `childrens` и у `bg_image` у Children

Comment: К тому же из документации можно сделать вывод что это поведение по умолчанию, и так есть для непосредственных отношений, но это не работает для отношений более глубоких

Comment: приведите полный пример кода, что создано и уже сброшено в базу а что только в памяти и как выдаются идентификаторы, сразу или по результату сброса в базу

Comment: @MikhailLazko дополнил текст вопроса

Comment: `merged_parent = session.merge(parent)` а статус вы проверяете на результирующем объекте? так как в доке сказано что исходный объект не меняется

Comment: В общем @MikhailLazko проблема была в том, что у одно из объектов был не существующий id а я это упустил вот  insert для него выполнялся. Спасибо!